# Check if a screen is active and then display countdown

Tags: 12.04, bash, backup, screen

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
Backup_from="/home/mc/server/prison/"
Backup_to="/home/mc/backups/PRISON-$DATE.tar" 

echo "Starting backup of $Backup_from to $Backup_to"
screen -dmS backup tar -zcvpf $Backup_to $Backup_from
if ! screen -list | grep -q "backup"; then
    for i in {10..1};do echo -n "$i." && sleep 1; done 
fi
echo "Done"
```

This is my current backup script, I want it to show a countdown while the screen is active. But then stop when its inactive/removed/deleted.

Comment: And what problem do you have?

Comment: I suggest you change your `.tar` destination with `tar.gz`, as you are using -z option (`gzip`).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do some countdown, **while** screen is active? If so, you could change your `if` and `for` with `while` loop, like this:

```
while (screen -list backup|grep -q backup); do
    # delay
    sleep 1

    # display another dot
    echo -n .
done
```

This displays a dot every second until your `screen` session terminates.
As for countdown, how would you even know proper starting time (how many seconds to count)?

---

As alternate, if you want repeating animation of 3 dots:

```
# init counter
i=0;
while (screen -list backup|grep -q backup); do
    # delay
    sleep 1

    # display dot
    echo -n "."

    # increase conter
    i=$((i+1))

    # on every 3rd loop...
    if [ $i -gt 3 ]; then
        # ...reset counter...
        i=0

        # ...and clear current line and return the cursor
        echo -en "\r\e[K"
    fi
done
```

Comment: IS there a way to make like  loading thing, sorta like doing . then .. then ... so its like an animated ...

Comment: It does exactly so - 1 dot every 1 second, but exact number of dots is unknown.

Comment: Or you want repeating 1 to 3 dots only?

Comment: repeating 1 to 3 only